# MPI_Gather prime number arrays into one array

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to split up a program that calculates whether or not a number is a prime. So, I spread out into each process a range of numbers and find the primes in that range. This works, each process takes the range and finds the correct primes. Then when I want to Gather all of the arrays from each process into one is where I am running into problems.

Either it prints out the proper number of array values, but has extra 0's so it will print out something like `2,3,5,7,0,11,13,0,0,0,17,19...` or I get the assertion failed error where the memcpy argument memory ranges overlap.

Here is the relevant code in my main -

```
  thesePrimes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * maxNumberOfTotalPrimes);

  //findPrimes returns k which is the number of primes found and
  //puts all of the prime numbers from this process into thesePrimes.
  //n is the highest number to check if prime (ie n = 100 check for primes
  //less than 100)
  k = findPrimes(thesePrimes, start, end, n);

  //Reduce k to get the total number of primes within the input
  MPI_Reduce(&k, &numberOfPrimes, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  //Allocate just enough space to hold all of the primes based on the reduced
  //number of primes
  allPrimes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfPrimes);

  //Gather each process's thesePrimes into allPrimes using k as the buffer
  //size since k is the number of primes for the process, just send k numbers
  MPI_Gather(thesePrimes, k, MPI_INT, allPrimes, k, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if(myRank == 0) {
    printf("Attempting to print...\n");
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfPrimes; i++)
        printf("allPrimes[%d]=%d\n", i, allPrimes[i]);

    printf("There are %d prime numbers in the range 0 to %d\n", numberOfPrimes, n);
  }
```

Here is my function to find the number of primes -

```
int findPrimes(int primes[], int start, int end, int n){
    //k is used to count the number of primes
    int i, j, maxJ, k = 0;
    int isPrime = 1;

    printf("Finding primes from %d to %d\n", start, end);

    if(end > n) end = n;
    if(start == 0) start = 2;

    for(i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        maxJ = sqrt(i);

        for(j = 2; j <= maxJ; j++) {
            if(i%j == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("Checking if %d is prime...\n", i);
        if(isPrime) {
         primes[k++] = i;
         printf("%d is a prime number.\n", primes[k-1]);
        }
        else isPrime = 1;
//      printf("Prime check complete.\n");
    }
    printf("k = %d\n", k);
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `MPI_Gather()` the number of prime numbers on each rank, and then you will be able to `MPI_Gatherv()` the prime numbers.

Comment: What is the gatherv for?

Comment: `k` is different on each rank, so you need two steps in order to gather all the prime numbers.

Comment: I've honestly looked at a couple of gatherv examples, and still having trouble figuring out how to implement. Can you give an example please?